# Is war a legal way to deal with the actions of non-state actors?

Tags: international-law

I understand that there are a thousand shades of grey between explicit state actors (think Israeli citizens on the payroll of the IDF and operating according to orders given them through an explicit chain of command) and non-state ideologues (think Al-Qaeda members funded by profits from construction and similarly legal enterprises). Supposing we were only talking about pure ideologues who committed a [dastardly and high profile enough to cause a war if a state had performed these actions] crime, what recourse would a targeted country have, legally speaking?

Comment: It will partly depend on specific legal agreements between the nations. If A has an extradition agreement with B and someone living in B attacked A, then A may be able to request the extradition of suspects. There are also international agreements, such as those around Interpol, and regional agreements, as in the EU.

Comment: A related post at sister site Law.SE: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/17228/is-the-united-states-at-war

Answer (score 10):

You can demand that the country in which the non-state actors are based deals with them. If that state does deal with them, then you have no need of war. If that state refuses, or is unable to deal with the group, then your conflict is with the state.  How you proceed is then a matter for diplomacy or violence.

You should ask for UNSC support in this.  The UNSC can authorise force against a nation that refuses to control a non-state actor that disrupts the peace. Or it can authorise support to a nation that is unable to control a group (even if that state is unwilling).  If the UNSC does not authorise force, you can still act on the basis of self-defence.  How this will be perceived depends on the proportionality of your response and your general standing in the world community.

Comment: *then your conflict is with the state* I would not put it that way, specially if it is a matter of being unable of controlling the group rather than unwilling. E.g., the downing of a civilian airplane by Ukrainian separatists did not men a conflict with Ukraine, and had three been reprisals, those would have been directed against the separatist republics rather than against Ukraine. In that scenario, three only possibility of Ukraine being attacked would be if it tried to stop the attacks as a way of seeing sovereignty.

Comment: Another example could be the attack on Bin Laden's hideout, which was not against the government of Pakistan (although it certainly did violate its sovereignty)

Comment: I would agree with this, and the specific context matters, which is why "how you proceed is a matter for diplomacy".  The capability of the country to take action will differ greatly.  Malaysai doesn't have the capacity to enter a conflict in Eastern Ukraine.  The US does have the capacity to scale a special forces attack on Bin Laden.

Answer (score 2):

Legally speaking it depends on whether or not, the country/countries is a party to some convention like the Geneva Convention by which their conduct as belligerents vis-à-vis the relevant articles *"(e.g., Legal status of the Parties to the conflict, Protection of civilian medical and religious personnel,  Safeguard of an enemy hors de combat etc.)"* are bound to.

However, it gets legally complicated fast when only one party, regardless if state or non-state actor, is a signatory of such a convention. The only legal difference, as far as a non-state actor is concerned is that, they are only held accountable if, their status has already been defined in such a convention.

Which is why the [International Legion of Defense of Ukraine](https://ildu.com.ua/) are not mercenaries under the Additional Protocol to the Geneva Conventions (API), because the Ukrainian government has formally incorporated the Legion’s reported 20,000 foreign members including 3,000 Americans, into its armed forces, in other words although both Russia/Ukraine are signatories of the four Geneva Conventions, the Ukrainian state recognizes the International Legion of Defense of Ukraine as [foreign] volunteers but the Russian state sees them as mercenaries, and each deals with them accordingly.

The old adage of "one's man freedom fighter is another man's terrorist" comes to mind. [See](https://www.icct.nl/publication/foreign-fighters-foreign-volunteers-and-mercenaries-ukrainian-armed-conflict)

> Shortly after the expanded Russian invasion of Ukraine on 24 February
> 2022, President Zelensky created the International Legion for the
> Territorial Defence of Ukraine, and began calling for (foreign)
> volunteers to join. A special website has been dedicated to assist
> foreign volunteers to come and support Ukraine. Since the start of the
> conflict, Ukraine claims that approximately 20,000 individuals have
> joined the Ukrainian armed forces.
>
> Foreign individuals also joined the Russian side of the conflict.
> Russian President Vladimir Putin has announced that 16,000 volunteers
> from the Middle East are ready to support Russia. Foreigners from
> Chechnya and mercenaries joining the Wagner Group from Syria and Libya
> are included.
>
> Considering the  death sentence imposed on two British and Moroccan
> fighters pronounced by a pro-Russian court in East Ukraine, and the
> recent capture of two American fighters in Donetsk, this perspective
> addresses the legal status of the foreign individuals joining the
> conflict in Ukraine, and some of the legal and political consequences
> of this situation. It provides an overview of some of the salient
> features of international humanitarian law, offers definitions of the
> terms ‘foreign volunteer’, ‘foreign terrorist fighter’ and
> ‘mercenary’, explains why these distinctions matter, and explores what
> lessons can be drawn from conflating or exchanging these different
> terms.

Answer (score 1):

If the non-state actors - let's call them insurgents for clarity - are foreign based, or foreign supplied, declaring war on that foreign nation is a legal (legal is a complicated word in this context, but I think I know what you mean) response, if the response is proportionate and related to the issue you're claiming to want to resolve.

If the insurgents control territory in your state and are supported by at least parts of the  population in that territory, we're talking about a civil war. Civil wars are barely covered by international law, because they are national matters, and because the insurgent party usually cannot represent itself on the international stage.

Comment: How can you declare war on a nation for things that people not under their control are doing?

Comment: By asking the nation that's hosting or supporting these people to stop them, and if the nation is unwilling or unable to do so, your army crosses into the territory of that nation (an act of war) and you stop them yourself.

Comment: @JoeW Yes. This was precisely what happened in the case of the Authorization for Use of Military Force in 2001.

Comment: @JoeW Claiming territory that’s not under your control is a foolish thing to do, because it does make you responsible for what happens there. If you don’t want people declaring war on you as a result, you should formally renounce that territory.

Comment: @MikeScott Still not sure how you declare war on a foreign nation for actions of non state actors regardless of what territory they claim to control

Comment: @JoeW So "non state actors" from nation X cross a border to nation Y and plunder and pillage and return home; and their home nation refuses to do anything about them, nation Y has no recourse? That's one way to carry on a war; nation X is at peace with nation Y, and the fact that heavily armed citizens from nation X keep massacring in nation Y is not a problem, but state actors from nation Y stepping across the border in pursuit, that's nation Y starting a war.

Comment: @prosfilaes just because they are in nation x doesn’t mean that nation can actually do anything about it.

Comment: @JoeW On one hand, often the nation can do something about it; as in the hypothetical I gave, countries often use deniable forces to do what they don't want to be held responsible for. On the other, I don't see where that's nation Y's problem; does nation Y have no response to the ongoing murder of its citizens because of nation X's failure?

Comment: @prosfilaes Can they? Think about Israel and Hamas and all the issues there. Hamas is operating in Israel but there is little that seems to be able to be done about the actions being taken.

Comment: @JoeW Israel Hamas is a Civil War, Gaza is not a country. Unless you're referring to Israel using the Civil War as a legal pretext for attacking Iran, which is certainly plausible.

Comment: @Peter But you are still talking about non state actors that are taking actions that may cause other nations to want to retaliate and it isn't anything that the nations that they are in can control.

Comment: @JoeW In any case, there are cases where the country can stop it and doesn't care to, and I believe that that is a just cause for war. You want to respond to that before going off into other cases?

Comment: @prosfilaes Sorry, I don't agree with the idea that the actions of a non state actor are ever justification to declare war on a country.

Comment: @JoeW So if the US gave a bunch of weapons from the military to various people, who then used them to try and annex various Central American countries, nobody would have any just response as long as they got back to the safety of the US? That if Iranians nuked Tel Aviv, it's up to Iran to deal with the group that somehow got their hand on a nuclear weapon?

Comment: @prosfilaes You are making a lot of hypothetical questions there though you can actually say that the US has supported overthrowing governments before in the past. As for the hypothetical nuking that depends on how the group got the weapon. If they got it from an unrelated third party why should Iran be punished for something they had no control over?

Comment: @JoeW When you go "are [n]ever justification", you're inviting hypotheticals. American non-state actors have acted to overthrow governments before; is no response allowed?

Comment: @JoeW Iran should not be invaded to "punish" them. In this hypothetical, Iran should be invaded if they don't do anything about it, because a non-state actor running around with nukes destabilizes the world order. It is arguable to invade them because they have taken actions or lack thereof that led to tens of thousands of deaths and could lead to tens of thousands more, if the rest of the world doesn't do anything. Iran is a stable government; they do have the ability to take action against terrorist groups on their soil.

Comment: @prosfilaes Your scenario said that the group had already used the nuclear weapon that they had, not that they still had more and that Iran was doing nothing to get the weapons out of their hands. You are suggesting that it is acceptable for a country to be invaded for actions that they had nothing to do with and is possible that they had no knowledge of. It could easily be possible that in your scenario a third party gave the weapon to the non state actors just so they could justify attacking Iran in the first place.

Comment: @prosfilaes I am not saying anything about American non-state actors, I am saying that American State actors have worked with non American state actors in order to attempt to overthrow governments. If you instead target the country that those non state actors reside in you would be targeting the wrong people and not the ones that are responsible in the first place.

Comment: @JoeW suppose a bunch of people in northern New Hampshire with no connection to any government start launching rockets at Sherbrooke, Quebec.  What would happen?  The US would arrest and prosecute them, using paramilitary or military force if necessary.  Canada, importantly for this question, has a right to _expect_ the US to do this, and if the US failed to do it, Canada would have a right -- indeed an obligation to its people -- to take matters into its own hands.  If it did so, there would be no reason to think that a declaration of war would be out of the question.

Comment: @phoog And I am saying if the US doesn't have the ability to do anything about it that doesn't justify declaring war against them.

Comment: @JoeW Your position is terribly far out of touch with reality.

Comment: @Servaes Just a country will declare war on another country because of the actions of non state actors doesn't mean it is the right thing to do. Countries do things they shouldn't be doing all the time.

Comment: @JoeW See my previous comment.

Comment: @Servaes again, just because a country does something and claims it is justified doesn’t make it actually justified. No matter how many times you say otherwise it won’t change my stance on that.

Comment: @JoeW A country not having the ability to do anything about it is only one side of this question. To some extent, a country can always do something about a problem like this on its soil: it can authorize the people being annoyed by it to come deal with it.

Comment: @prosfilaes and it still doesn’t justify declaring war on another country.

Comment: @JoeW What does? The attackers being state actors or not isn't much relevant to the attacked country, or the people of the country the attacking forces are coming from that isn't doing anything about it.

Comment: @prosfilaes Being upset about something isn't justification to declare war and attack someone who isn't responsible for the actions you are upset about.

Comment: @JoeW Being attacked by a paramilitary force with resulting civilian  casualties is not justification for responding militarily? The whole point is this war would be to attack the people responsible for the actions you are upset about. And with great power of a nation state comes the great responsibility for the actions of its inhabitants and citizens, which may not preventable, but can be responded to.

Comment: @prosfilaes If the force is a non state actor and has no connection to the country in question besides being based there that isn't a justification for declaring war on that country and killing people who have nothing to do with or any control over the group that you are actually mad at. No matter how many times you keep trying to convince me you won't change my mind on this. There is no justification to declare war on a country and kill it's civilian's for the act of a non state actor that they have no control over.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that there are a thousand shades of grey between explicit state actors (*think Israeli citizens on the payroll of the IDF and operating according to orders given them through an explicit chain of command*) and non-state ideologues (think Al-Qaeda members funded by profits from construction and similarly legal enterprises).

*Israeli citizens on the payroll of the IDF* is a dubious a figure of speech, creating the impression that Israel has a contract/professional army, rather than a general conscription - see [Israeli Defense Forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_Troops_of_Russia). It is like calling the US servicemen in Vietnam *the US citizens on the payroll of Pentagon*. Yes, they are getting paid, by they are not there by choice, just for the sake of money.

Note also that the military is more than just an armed force - it is a government sanctioned armed force, whose role is defined by the constitution/basic laws of the state, and which is subordinate to the the government. Its major role is typically defending the state and its citizens from an external aggression, although sometimes it also implies promoting the state interests abroad (like the US military does), disaster relief, etc.

Another way to view the government armed forces is as *a branch of
law enforcement*, dealing specifically with external threats, unlike, e.g., police, which deals with internal crime (although sometimes the distinction is blurred, like the [*Internal Troops*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_Troops_of_Russia).)

> Supposing we were only talking about *pure ideologues who committed a [dastardly and high profile enough to cause a war if a state had performed these actions] crime*, what recourse would a targeted country have, legally speaking?

What the question implies is more than *pure ideologues* - e.g., Marx&Engels were *pure ideologues*, but various communist regimes committing crimes in the name of their ideology were not *pure ideologues*.

Furthermore, it is worth noting that there are plenty of non-state actors:

- economic actors: corporations, non-profit organizations
- non-government educational institutions
- cultural organizations
- religious cults

and others.

All these may exercise legal or illegal activities on the territory of their own state and abroad. In case of illegal activities, it is the role of the law enforcement to deal with them. That is, in case of violent crimes, it is a matter for police, if the organization is native to the country, and a matter for the army, if the threat is external.

In case of an external threat it may involve sovereignty of the home state of the organization in question. This state may be asked to deal with the threat, and, depending on its response, may be assisted or itself considered an enemy (Indeed, refusal to deal with a threat to another state is a rather classical [casus belli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_belli).) To give a few examples:

- The classical case here is the supposed support to [Black Hand by Belgrade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Hand_(Serbia)), which was alleged by the Austro-Hungarian government after the [assassination its Crown Prince](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassination_of_Archduke_Franz_Ferdinand). The refusal of the Serbian government to undertake the emasures demanded by Austro-Hungary triggered World War 1.
- Al-Qaeda in Afghanistan was tolerated or even actively supported by Taliban regime, which prompted [the US and allies to confront *both* Taliban and Al-Qaeda, by invading Afghanistan and ousting Taliban from power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_invasion_of_Afghanistan).
- Al-Qaeda was also active in the neighboring Pakistan, using it as a safe haven for its fighters, and leaders. Pakistan was unable to deal with Al-Qaeda on its own, but tolerated the US cross-border raids and other activities by *the US citizens on the payroll of Pentagon* - culminating in the assassination of [Osama Bin Laden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_of_Osama_bin_Laden).
- A less clear case is various cross-border [operations by Turkish military against Kurds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurdish%E2%80%93Turkish_conflict_(1978%E2%80%93present)) in Iraq and more recently in Syria. Turkey largely gets away with this due to its military superiority vis-à-vis the host countries.
- Lebanon is another example of a state unable to deal with a military organization within its borders: despite the [Israeli withdrawal from Southern Lebanon in 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israeli_occupation_of_Southern_Lebanon) and the [UNSC resolution demanding the disarmament of Hezbollah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Security_Council_Resolution_1701), it continues to exist and openly attack the neighboring state. Lately Hezbollah is obstructing the US efforts to resolve the border disputes between Lebanon and Israel, despite the [Lebanese government willingness to negotiate](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/2024/01/05/nasrallah-hezbollah-israel-border-fighting/).
- *Hamas* and other Palestinian paramilitary organizations in Gaza are also non-state actors - not only because the Palestinian state is not universally recognized, but also because they exist outside of the [Palestinian National Security Forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinian_National_Security_Forces), which the Palestinian Authority is entitled to according to the Oslo Accords. Notably, in The PA inability and alleged unwillingness to deal with the threat that these organizations pose to Israeli citizens is largely responsible for the collapse of the Oslo accords, and the political rise of Benjamin Netanyahu and other politicians, not believing in the possibility of co-existence with the PA.

Answer (score -1):

## Yes

First of all, anything that's not illegal is legal.  So in the absence of a law either authorizing or forbidding an action, that action is legal.  For example, you don't have a license authorizing you to breathe because you don't need one.  There is no law forbidding it, so it's legal.

As for states using military resources to dismantle rogue militant formations, which may or may not act [under the color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_(law)) of a governing entity, it is both **legal and** **customary** to do so.

The examples of states using military against such entities are numerous, but here's just a few:

- Jordan's military fighting PLO in Jordan in a series of events which came to be known as [Black September](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_September).
- NATO invasion of Afghanistan to fight Al Qaeda after 9/11 attacks by Al Qaeda operatives against the US.
- US military attacks against ISIS in Iraq and Syria.
- France retaliating against ISIS attacks in Paris (November 13, 2015), aka Charlie Hebdo attacks, by bombing ISIS seat of power in Al-Raqqah, Syria.
- Ukraine fighting Russian proxies in Donbas, between 2014 and 2022, in response to those Russian proxies taking over parts of the region of Ukraine without declaring an explicit affiliation with the Russian Federation.
- [Mexican military fighting against the drug cartels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican_drug_war).
- Colombian military fighting against the FARC guerrillas.